# How to use % while writing a query in django using object.raw() function

Tags: django

I am a beginner in django , How to write a raw query in django which is similar to

```
"select * from table where column1 like '%a%'"
```

I am getting an error

> "not enough arguments for format string"

when i just use `"select * from table where column1 like 'a' "` . it is working .

Comment: What is `%a%` supposed to be?

Comment: i am trying to search for all the column1 words which have an "a" some where in them .

Comment: example : i want to search for all peoples whose name starts with a and have "a" as a character in their names then in raw sql i would write a query like "select * from names_tables where names like '%a%' or names like 'a%' " .

Comment: I tried using an escape character \ before % it is still giving the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double the percent signs, otherwise they are treated as placeholders.

```
"select * from table where column1 like '%%a%%'"
```

When you use raw sql, you can use `%s` for placeholders, for example:

```
Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])
```

That means that if you want a literal percent sign, you have to use `%%`. The Django docs on [executing custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) directly has an example of this.

Comment: Thanks it worked !! but can u tell me the reason behind the working . it is some special escape character ?